# Site.com: Use Reusable Custom Widget within Custom Code Page Element?

Tags: widget

See: [Site.com Timesavers: Reusable Custom Widgets](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/tech-pubs/2013/06/site-com-timesavers-reusable-custom-widgets.html).

Is there a way to access these widgets in `Custom Code Page Element` using a tag? I have page with a `Custom Code Page Element`, and I want to use a `Reusable Custom Widget` in that element.

Comment: What do you mean by widget? Please link to a reference or explain in more depth.

Comment: @AdrianLarson: Please check https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/tech-pubs/2013/06/site-com-timesavers-reusable-custom-widgets.html

Comment: Take a look at the new question, it is much more clear, no? Please try to include these kinds of details from the outset to help us understand where you are coming from. Welcome to SFSE!

Comment: Also, it is still unclear what you have tried, please include the steps you have taken so far and where you are stuck. The tutorial you linked seems to already cover this question in detail.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Tutorial has covered drag and drop. I am trying add this via code. something like       `${! widget.test}`